# Using django-widget-tweaks for multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-widget-tweaks

I use `django-widget-tweaks` for validation like this

```
{% if form.is_bound %}
    {% if form.action.errors %}
        {% render_field form.action class="form-control is-invalid"  %}
        {% for error in form.action.errors %}
            <div class="has-error">
              {{ error }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% render_field form.action class="form-control is-valid" %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% render_field form.action class="form-control" %}
{% endif %}
```

It works well but when I use two fields, my code will be.

```
{% if form.is_bound %}
    {% if form.action.errors %}
        {% render_field form.action class="form-control is-invalid"  %}
        {% for error in form.action.errors %}
            <div class="has-error">
              {{ error }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% render_field form.action class="form-control is-valid" %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% render_field form.action class="form-control" %}
{% endif %}
{% if form.is_bound %}
    {% if form.action2.errors %}
        {% render_field form.action2 class="form-control is-invalid"  %}
        {% for error in form.action2.errors %}
            <div class="has-error">
              {{ error }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% render_field form.action2 class="form-control is-valid" %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% render_field form.action2 class="form-control" %}
{% endif %}
```

It doesn't look cool... If I use three, four fields code will be longer and longer.

Is there any best practice for this purpose??

Comment: Please follow this link https://medium.com/@bhagyalakshmi18/uploading-multiple-files-in-django-b2f5ede55d09

Answer (score 0):

You can try set it in your Form class

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
     my_files_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':
True}))
```